# Can't update Nginx to version higher than 1.12.2 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, nginx

I have been trying to update Nginx to it's latest version in my ubuntu server.

So, I tried with this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nginx
```

But the result showing that **Nginx is already in the newest version (1.12.2-0+xenial0)**

[image]

Here's the output of `sudo apt-cache policy nginx`

[image]

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for terminal output. Instead, paste the terminal output into the question, select it, and press the `{}` button in the editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Pre-Built Packages for Mainline version Ubuntu 16.04

For Ubuntu, in order to authenticate the nginx repository signature and to eliminate warnings about missing PGP key during installation of the nginx package, it is necessary to add the key used to sign the nginx packages and repository to the apt program keyring. Please copy/paste into text file and rename nginx_signing.key in Home Directory this [key](https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key) from our web site, and add it to the apt program keyring with the following command:

[image: Copy and Pasted Saved Key in Home]

```
sudo apt-key add nginx_signing.key
```

Append the following to the end of the /etc/apt/sources.list file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ xenial nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ xenial nginx
```

For Ubuntu then run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

[SOURCE](https://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#distributions)

Comment: gpg: can't open 'nginx_signing.key': No such file or directory

Comment: Added more precise Instructions.

Answer (score 0):

1.12.2 is the current stable version of nginx.

If you want the mainline version of nginx you have to use the PPA `ppa:nginx/development` instead of `ppa:nginx/stable`