# Nginx installing failure

Tags: 16.04, command-line, nginx, synapse

I've read other questions but didn't find an answer to my issue. Also as newbie I'm more lost than usual.

Well the problem is that trying to install Nginx and trying to see if `ufw status` get `status: inactive`

After this I write `systemctl status nginx` and get the next result:

```
pipo@pipo-X542UV:~$ sudo  systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since mar 2018-02-06 17:39:07 CET; 14min ago

 feb 06 17:39:06 pipo-X542UV nginx[27941]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 
 [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
 feb 06 17:39:06 pipo-X542UV nginx[27941]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 
 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in us
 feb 06 17:39:06 pipo-X542UV nginx[27941]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 
 [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
 feb 06 17:39:07 pipo-X542UV nginx[27941]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 
 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in us
 feb 06 17:39:07 pipo-X542UV nginx[27941]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 
 [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
 feb 06 17:39:07 pipo-X542UV nginx[27941]: nginx: [emerg] still could 
 not bind()
 feb 06 17:39:07 pipo-X542UV systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control 
 process exited, code=exited status=1
 feb 06 17:39:07 pipo-X542UV systemd[1]: Failed to start A high 
 performance web server and a reverse proxy serve
 feb 06 17:39:07 pipo-X542UV systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered 
 failed state.
 feb 06 17:39:07 pipo-X542UV systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with 
 result 'exit-code'.
 lines 1-14/14 (END)
```

Have tried several times uninstalling and installing again

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Address already in use

Port 80 is in use.  Typically this means you have apache2 running, or another instance of nginx.

Comment: this means I should uninstall Apache?

Comment: @Caesar yes, you need to remove Apache or reconfigure Apache to use a different port before you can set up NGINX.

Comment: You can also disable it from starting up at boot and just shut it off.  There really is no need to have both installed, it's typically one or the other.

Comment: thanx! that worked fine

Comment: You Might be interested in this also....https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002470/cant-update-nginx-to-version-higher-than-1-12-2-in-ubuntu-16-04/1002481#1002481